# TFS Erro when try update workitem- You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I got that erro - You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.

```
public class TFSClient
{
    public WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WorkItem { get; set; }
    public TFSClient()
    {            
        VssCredentials vssCred = new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential(true));
        WorkItem = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(TFSServer.Url), vssCred);
    }
}
 public static object UpdateWorkItemByID(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument
            {
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {                       
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = ItemField.History,
                    Value = "Teste"
                }
            };            
            return  new TFSClient().WorkItem.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, id).Result;              

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

OBS: This method work before ,now i'm getting this erro and i dont know why.

Comment: ItemField.History, what is the namesapce of "ItemField"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1, as I got such error when use Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1 either.

This issue has been fixed in Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2, you could update Newtonsoft.Json to 11.0.2 and have another try.

Comment: Checked, i am using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1, update it to 11.0.2 and now is working, thanks.

Comment: I faced in the same issue and also update the to 11.0.2 solved it :) Thank you!